# Output different precision by column with pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, floating-point, pandas

### Question

Is it possible to specify a float precision specifically for each column to be printed by the Python `pandas` package method [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?

### Background

If I have a `pandas` dataframe that is arranged like this:

```
In [53]: df_data[:5]
Out[53]: 
    year  month  day       lats       lons  vals
0   2012      6   16  81.862745 -29.834254   0.0
1   2012      6   16  81.862745 -29.502762   0.1
2   2012      6   16  81.862745 -29.171271   0.0
3   2012      6   16  81.862745 -28.839779   0.2
4   2012      6   16  81.862745 -28.508287   0.0
```

There is the `float_format` option that can be used to specify a precision, but this applys that precision to all columns of the dataframe when printed.

When I use that like so:

```
df_data.to_csv(outfile, index=False,
                   header=False, float_format='%11.6f')
```

I get the following, where `vals` is given an inaccurate precision:

```
2012,6,16,  81.862745, -29.834254,   0.000000
2012,6,16,  81.862745, -29.502762,   0.100000
2012,6,16,  81.862745, -29.171270,   0.000000
2012,6,16,  81.862745, -28.839779,   0.200000
2012,6,16,  81.862745, -28.508287,   0.000000
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Change the type of column "vals" prior to exporting the data frame to a CSV file

```
df_data['vals'] = df_data['vals'].map(lambda x: '%2.1f' % x)

df_data.to_csv(outfile, index=False, header=False, float_format='%11.6f')
```

Comment: Note you're not just changing the type of vals, you're also rounding it. If it's not acceptable to modify the column, then could save it to a temporary column 'vals.numeric' while doing the to_csv() write.

Comment: this sets the numbers ok but it turns all the blanks in my column into 'nan' which makes its way to the csv also via to_csv and I'm not able to get rid of it.

Comment: To avoid the nan issue, my approach is `lambda x: '%2.1f % x if not pd.isna(x) else ''`

Answer (score 11):

The more current version of hknust's first line would be:

```
df_data['vals'] = df_data['vals'].map(lambda x: '{0:.1}'.format(x))
```

To print without scientific notation:

```
df_data['vals'] = df_data['vals'].map(lambda x: '{0:.1f}'.format(x))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that values are changed to strings

Answer (score 10):

This question is a bit old, but I'd like to contribute with a better answer, I think so:

```
formats = {'lats': '{:10.5f}', 'lons': '{:.3E}', 'vals': '{:2.1f}'}

for col, f in formats.items():
    df_data[col] = df_data[col].map(lambda x: f.format(x))
```

I tried with the solution [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values), but it didn't work for me, I decided to experiment with previus solutions given here combined with that from the link above.

Comment: The link you posted is for generated CSS for display in a Jupyter notebook, so if that won't work if you'd like your resulting CSV formatted. The chosen answer her that you've adapted converts all columns to (formatted) string data-types. for the format string, the pefered Python3.6+ way would be now be `f"{x:2.1f}"` rather than `"%2.1f" % x`.

Comment: Now I fixed the problem. Thanks @ryanjdillon

Answer (score 6):

You can use [round](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) method for dataframe before saving the dataframe to the file.

```
df_data = df_data.round(6)
df_data.to_csv('myfile.dat')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_string). There is a `formatters` argument where you can provide a dict of columns names to formatters. Then you can use some regexp to replace the default column separators with your delimiter of choice.

Comment: This also seems like a good method. I wonder what is more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested to see which is more efficient, but I would have to guess this one since it does not modify the dataframe...

Comment: hi @matlexx if would be great if you could elaborate on this. The `.to_string()` method merely converts the df to one concatenated string at my end. I can't see how one can send the output of this to `.to_csv()`

Comment: @NikhilVJ I think `.to_string()` should be able to do all that `.to_csv()` does.

Comment: @MilindR I just tried using formatters={"Cloud Cover": "%g"} in .to_csv() but got a `TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'formatters'`

Comment: @MatthijsKramer I did not imply that `.to_csv()` can do all that `.to_string()` does. Anyway, I tried out `.to_string()` and results in a single string with multi-space separators. I'm probably going the convert-to-string-type-columns-before-to_csv route for my work.

Comment: @MilindR Reading your comment again I see I interpreted your statement the wrong way around... Either way, it would be nice if the to_csv method could use formatters.

Answer (score 2):

The `to_string` approach suggested by @mattexx looks better to me, since it doesn't modify the dataframe.

It also generalizes well when using `jupyter` notebooks to get pretty HTML output, via the `to_html` method. Here we set a new default precision of 4, and override it to get 5 digits for a particular column `wider`:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import display

pd.set_option('precision', 4)

display(HTML(df.to_html(formatters={'wider': '{:,.5f}'.format})))
```

Comment: I love this idea, and agree with your argumentation, but `formatters` argument is not available for [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function...

Comment: @Géraud Thanks. That's too bad - maybe you can file an issue? But maybe they figure that rounding the data for purposes of a file export like csv makes less sense, and there are a bunch of ways to display csv files in tabular format with their own customizable ways of determining precision.