# Round in pandas column scientific numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a df  such as :

```
COL1        COL2
0.005554    0.35200000000000004
5.622e-11   0.267
0.006999999999999999    0.307
2.129e-14   0.469
2.604e-14   0.39
1.395e-60   0.27899999999999997
8.589999999999998e-74   0.29600000000000004
1.025e-42   0.4270000000000001
```

I knwo how to roun the digit in the COL2 by using

```
df['COL2'] = df['COL2'].round(3)
```

but if I do the same for COL1 it only displays 0

how can I get instead:

```
COL1        COL2
0.005   0.352
5.622e-11   0.267
0.007   0.307
2.129e-14   0.469
2.604e-14   0.39
1.395e-60   0.279
8.560e-74   0.296
1.025e-42   0.427
```

in fact the big issue is here:

it displays : `8.589999999999998e-74`
and I would like to keep only 3 number after the coma

```
8.590e-74
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to round the values in the first column - rounding means that the lower digits are gone. I think what you actually want to do is to change how Pandas displays the data *on screen* and not the actual values in the dataframe. The default is already scientific notation.

You can specify the display format for all columns like so (this will be showing the first three digits after the dot):

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
```

Since you want to keep the format of the first one but not of the second you might need to set the format for each column individually. You can use [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) for column 2:

```
df.style.format({'COL2': '{:.3f}')
```

Edit: Since your answer is for saving to CSV, you'll need to pass this as an argument to `to_csv`: `float_format='{:.3E}'`. This will save all columns in scientific notation. If you only want this for column 1, you could try the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003290/output-different-precision-by-column-with-pandas-dataframe-to-csv).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to do this for display purposes, you can set

```py
pd.options.display.precision = 3
print(df)
```

or to only do so in a temporary context:

```py
with pd.option_context('display.precision', 3):
    print(df)
```

Comment: I need to save the dataframe by using to_csv after, so it is not for a displaying perpose

Answer (score 0):

are lines 1 and 3 of the resulting dataframe also 0?
because all other lines are 0 when rounded to the 3rd decimal because 5.622e-11 is 0.00000000005622 thus rounded to 3 decimals it is 0.

Comment: This is more of a comment. Please consider relocate it under the question as such.

Comment: That was what I initially wanted to do, but my reputation is still to low unfortunately.