# File size mismatch while saving CSV to Parquet and back to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parquet

I am trying to save huge csv files to parquet format and then converting the file back to csv. But when I run following code the final csv file size is different than original file size

```
    import pandas as pd

    # Read CSV file
    csvFile = 'test.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csvFile)

    # Display data file details
    csvFileSize = ((os.path.getsize(csvFile)/1024)/1024)/1024
    print("CSV File Size (GB)     : ", csvFileSize)
    print("Data Details           : ", df.shape)

    # Save as Parquet
    parquetFile = csvFile.replace('csv', 'parquet')
    df.to_parquet(parquetFile, index=None)
    parquetFileSize = ((os.path.getsize(csvFile.replace('csv','parquet'))/1024)/1024)/1024
    print("Parquet File Size (GB) : ", parquetFileSize)
    print("Storage Size Saved     : ", round(100 - (parquetFileSize/csvFileSize)*100,2), "%")

    # Read Parquet file and save as CSV
    df = pd.read_parquet(parquetFile)
    csvFile = 'Reconverted_' + csvFile
    df.to_csv(csvFile, index=False)
    csvFileSize = ((os.path.getsize(csvFile)/1024)/1024)/1024
    print("Reconverted CSV (GB)   : ", csvFileSize)
    print("Data Details           : ", df.shape)
```

The output is as follows

```
    CSV File Size (GB)     :  6.168231673538685
    Data Details           :  (3679839, 55)
    Parquet File Size (GB) :  1.0481115290895104
    Storage Size Saved     :  83.01 %
    Reconverted CSV (GB)   :  6.157632351852953
    Data Details           :  (3679839, 55)
```

Am I missing something out here

Comment: Have you looked at the file content, i.e. compared the first few lines? I coudl imaging that there could be a difference in decimal characters. What does the file contain, can you post example data?

Comment: The file contains invoice details like account no, amount and yes it is in decimal. Let me check through those columns.

Comment: I found the issue with the decimal points while storing. The decimal number with  the length of 18  i.e 26.486444642466772 gets stored as 26.48644464246677. But my other columns with the length lesser than18 get stored as it is ie 0.020719985231939 or 0.54879874183848. Now is it possible for me to store few data columns with different length ?

Comment: Do you actually need that amount of precision? But if you do, then `to_csv` does not have an option to format per column. The best approach then is to convert your columns tos trings prior to saving, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003290/output-different-precision-by-column-with-pandas-dataframe-to-csv)